# javascriptで端末のカメラを起動してシャッタースピードを変更したいです。

Tags: javascript, camera, webapi

javascriptを使って端末のカメラを起動するwebアプリを作成しています。
現在、getUserMediaを使って、起動したカメラの設定をいじっているおりまして、端末の画面にはリアカメラの映像を映し出すことが出来ています。
ですが、シャッタースピードを変更する方法が分かっていない状態です。

参考サイト
[Web でカメラを使おう – WebRTC (getUserMedia) on WebView](https://houwa-js.co.jp/2019/06/20190604/)

getUserMediaでは、シャッタースピードの変更はできないのでしょうか。
また、それ以外にシャッタースピードを設定する方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

こちらの記事とそこからのリンク先が類似の話題を扱っているようですが、おそらくChromeでしか動作しない実験的なAPIを使えば出来るのかもしれません。
[getUserMedia lock focus/exposure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29324556/9014308)

> What I would like to do is, once the page starts taking snapshots, lock the getUserMedia camera's focus/exposure, so that in between snapshot intervals the environment can change without the light balance changing or the camera refocusing.
> 私がやりたいのは、ページがスナップショットの撮影を開始したら、getUserMediaカメラのフォーカス/露出をロックして、スナップショットの間隔の間に、ライトバランスを変更したりカメラの焦点を合わせ直したりせずに環境を変更できるようにすることです。

> Not yet. Unfortunately, WebRTC does not allow photo-level access to cameras, but a new Image Capture spec is being worked on to solve this. None of the browsers implement it yet though. >未だに。 残念ながら、WebRTCはカメラへの写真レベルのアクセスを許可していませんが、これを解決するために新しいImageCapture仕様に取り組んでいます。 ただし、どのブラウザもまだ実装していません。

[Take photo when the camera is automatically focused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47637708/9014308)
[Why the difference in native camera resolution -vs- getUserMedia on iPad / iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52900311/9014308)

---

この辺の記事を読むと、`exposure`とか`iso`に関連する情報を操作することで、間接的にシャッタースピードを操作出来るように見えます。

[シャッター速度 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6) / [Shutter speed - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_speed)

> シャッター速度（シャッターそくど、英: Shutter speed ）は、カメラによる写真撮影の際、シャッターが開放され、フィルムまたは撮像素子がレンズを通した光にさらされる（露出する）時間（露光時間、シャッタースピード、「SS」とも略される）をいう。

[CAMERA EXPOSURE](https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/camera-exposure.htm)

[MediaStream Image Capture](https://www.w3.org/TR/image-capture/)

> W3C Working Draft, 6 April 2021
> [9.4. MediaTrackSettings dictionary](https://www.w3.org/TR/image-capture/#mediatracksettings-section)
> DOMString         exposureMode;
> double            exposureCompensation;
> double            exposureTime;
> double            iso;

[MediaStream Image Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Image_Capture_API)

> Experimental
> これは実験的な機能です。
> 本番で使用する前にブラウザー互換性一覧表をチェックしてください。

[Web でカメラを使おう – WebRTC (getUserMedia) on WebView](https://houwa-js.co.jp/2019/06/20190604/)

> 細かい制御
> 参考までに各ブラウザでの実行結果を載せておきます。
> Google Chrome
>
> "exposureCompensation": true,
> "exposureMode": true,
> "exposureTime": true,
> "iso": true,

---

何かキーワードで関連しそうなもの
[Q. USBカメラの露出値と露光時間（シャッタースピード）の関係](http://faq.hozan.co.jp/support/faq/detail?site=ZAWBTM42&id=239)
[LinuxでUVC(USB Video Class)タイプのUSBカメラを使う](https://qiita.com/nonbiri15/items/9593d61a2be81f2b31a9)
[ガイドカメラ](http://norikyu.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_11.html)
[Pythonでカメラを制御する【研究用】](https://qiita.com/opto-line/items/7ade854c26a50a485159)

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます！非常に参考になりました。
いただいた情報を元に実験してみたいと思います！

Comment: 色々と試してみましたが、getUserMediaでの「iso」と「exposure」の設定方法がどこにも記述がなく分かりませんでした。。。また、以下の記事（2019更新）の時点では、詳細な設定方法などは公開されていないとの記述がありました。
https://houwa-js.co.jp/2019/06/20190604/#usage